# Inconsistent results for Flink SQL Continuous Window Top-N query

Tags: flink-streaming, flink-sql

For Flik Kafka SQL source definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PlayEvents (
  `event_time` TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'timestamp',
  `the_kafka_key` STRING, 
  `song_id` BIGINT NOT NULL, 
  `duration` BIGINT, 
  WATERMARK FOR `event_time` AS `event_time` - INTERVAL '1' SECONDS 
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'kafka', 
  'topic' = 'play-events',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:29092',
  'key.format' = 'raw',
  'key.fields' = 'the_kafka_key',
  'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
  'value.avro-confluent.url' = 'http://localhost:8081',
  'value.fields-include' = 'EXCEPT_KEY',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset'
)
```

Test `PlayEvent` messages are sent to the `play-events` every `100ms`
using the Avro format:

```java
protocol `protocol` {
    record PlayEvent {
        long song_id;
        long duration;
    }
}
```

I'm running a continuous [Window Top-N](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-topn/) query:

```java
Configuration strConf = new Configuration();
strConf.setInteger(RestOptions.PORT, 8089);
strConf.setString(RestOptions.BIND_PORT, "8088-8090");

StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(strConf);
StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
Configuration tableConfiguration = tableEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration();
tableConfiguration.setString("table.exec.source.idle-timeout", "2 min");

tableEnv.sqlQuery("" +
    "SELECT window_end, song_id, play_count FROM ( " +
    " SELECT *, " +
    "    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY window_start, window_end ORDER BY play_count DESC) AS row_num " +
    " FROM (" +
    "    SELECT window_start, window_end, song_id, COUNT(*) AS play_count " +
    "    FROM TABLE( " +
    "      TUMBLE(TABLE PlayEvents, DESCRIPTOR(event_time), INTERVAL '60' SECONDS)) " +
    "    GROUP BY window_start, window_end, song_id " +
    " ) " +
    ") WHERE row_num <= 4 "
).execute().print();
```

The first printed output, after starting, shows consistent results having exactly 4 results for each window period:

```sh
...
| +I | 2021-11-04 12:23:00.000 |                    3 |                   16 |
| +I | 2021-11-04 12:23:00.000 |                    6 |                   14 |
| +I | 2021-11-04 12:23:00.000 |                    1 |                   12 |
| +I | 2021-11-04 12:23:00.000 |                   11 |                   10 |

| +I | 2021-11-04 12:24:00.000 |                    9 |                   16 |
| +I | 2021-11-04 12:24:00.000 |                    6 |                   13 |
| +I | 2021-11-04 12:24:00.000 |                    7 |                   12 |
| +I | 2021-11-04 12:24:00.000 |                    5 |                   12 |
```

The follow up outputs though show some partial windows content:

```
...
| +I | 2021-11-04 12:25:00.000 |                    9 |                   12 |
| +I | 2021-11-04 12:25:00.000 |                    6 |                    6 |

| +I | 2021-11-04 12:27:00.000 |                   11 |                   18 |
...
```

E.g. the window contains only 1, 2, 3 elements per interval and sometime the entire interval is dropped.

If I restart the query all results will be shown correctly (e.g. exactly 4 elements per window ..) on the first print and then it will continue with the partial responses.

I've tried different configurations, tried to write the continuous query into another Kafka topic and then query it from there. But the inconsistent partial result remains.

Not sure if I'm missing some important configuration or this is a known limitation or issue with Flink?

P.S. i'm testing with Flink 1.14 running my tests on local machine.

Answer (score 0):

When a Flink job that does event time processing exhibits non-deterministic behavior, this is because processing time is, in some way, influencing the results. In this case my guess is that the actual out-of-orderness exceeds the 1 second interval configured in the watermarking, leading to late events that are then being dropped.

The `idle-timeout` could also play a role here. When a source that was marked idle resumes delivering events, it can easily be the case that the watermark has already moved past the timestamps in the initial events coming from that previously idle source. Even if one second is enough to handle the normally expected out-of-orderness, it might not be long enough in this special case.

Comment: Thanks David! I've been trying differed watermark intervals with no success. For the sake of the experiment I've just increased the PlayEvents' Watermark to to 30 secs and bumped the idle-timeout to 5 min. Unfortunately still same result.
I resorted to the idle-timeout  because without it the query never starts.  So in this case i had to wait for 5 min before the first result pops up. Then it (more or less) prints result as expected every 1 m. Just that the results are incomplete.

Comment: Could it be that there are intervals that don't have data for 4 different songs? Also, it's unusual that you have to set the idle-timeout. This suggests that you have at least one Kafka partition that doesn't have much data.

Comment: _... don't have data for 4 different songs?_
Not likely. Sending 10 msg/sec from 14 songs. Furthermore if I re-run the same-query,  the first print will show all results correctly (e.g. 4 entries/window) even for the windows it did miss in the previous run.


_it's unusual that you have to set the idle-timeout. This suggests that you have at least one Kafka partition that doesn't have much data._
Is there are way to verify this? Here is the Kafka+SchemaReg i'm using for the test:[docker-compose-kafka.yml](https://gist.github.com/tzolov/4f93f60ef1310caf38219195e1b31405)

Comment: Also, Isn't this suggesting that there is only one partition for the `play-events` topic: `Topic: play-events TopicId: KEzc4NxISqySFa6czLKMuw PartitionCount: 1 ReplicationFactor: 1 Configs: Topic: play-events Partition: 0 Leader: 1001 Replicas: 1001 Isr: 1001`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the [defaultLocalParallelism](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/942bc87e34cbcd17201646790d75625740ce83ad/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/environment/StreamExecutionEnvironment.java#L166) that equals the number of machine cores (`16` in my case). In result 16 sub-tasks are spawn `but only one is used` to process the input data (the input Kafka topic uses only 1 partition).

If I set the `parallelism` explicitly to `1` the idle timeout and the query result inconsistencies are resolved:

```java
Configuration strConf = ...
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(1, strConf);
```

Or you can set it like this:

```java
env.getConfig().setParallelism(1);
```

P.S. Thought this solved my demo problem, I wonder what would be the proper approach to configure the parallelism/max-parallelism for local environments.